# Emulator display in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, emulation

I need help to get what could be wrong with the emulator in Android Studio. After the last update it shows in this way (image). I've tried to update the emulator, delete the virtual device and create a new one but it still showing this size. Does anyone know if it's a configuration problem or where should I look for?

[Emulator display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4iVJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is often caused by problems with HAXM\HAXM issues also conflicts with other virtualization technologies, that could be  incorrect settings, or an out-of-date HAXM driver.  Try to reinstalling the HAXM driver.